# Bootstrap grid breaks on xs viewport

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I am trying to arrange 4 images horizonally (4x1) on viewports small and greater, and in a 2x2 grid on x-small view ports.

However, the third image is floating right when I resize to xs.

I've tried stripping out all the other classes I've added, and changing the pictures, but to no avail.

```
<div class="row margin-100-top margin-100-bot">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 margin-10-eql">
            <img src="/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/images/nw_csr_volunteering.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 margin-10-eql">
            <img src="/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/images/nw_manchester_volunteering.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 margin-10-eql">
            <img src="/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/images/nw_manchester_volunteers.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 margin-10-eql">
            <img src="/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/images/nw_leeds_volunteering.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://dev.benefacto.org/north/

(My margin classes only add margin above, fyi)

Many thanks for your help,

Ben

Comment: thats because 4 x 6 doesn't = 12. All columns in a grid must add up to 12

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm well aware that 4x6 doesn't make 12; what I'm looking for is on an xs screen port I will have one row of two col-xs-6 blocks, and then the next two blocks on the row below. Is that problematic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to yaylitzis's answer is to remove the bottom margin from image one like this:

```
<div class="row margin-100-top margin-100-bot">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6" style="margin-top:10px">
        <img src="/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/images/nw_csr_volunteering.jpg" alt="corporate volunteers in Liverpool">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 margin-10-eql">
        <img src="/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/images/nw_manchester_volunteering.jpg" alt="corporate volunteers in Manchester">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 margin-10-eql">
        <img src="/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/images/nw_manchester_volunteers.jpg" alt="corporate volunteers in Sheffield">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 margin-10-eql">
        <img src="/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/images/nw_leeds_volunteering.jpg" alt="Corporate Volunteers in Leeds">
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">
            <h1 class="white margin-30-top text-center big">Benefacto helps people organise and run meaningful
                 employee volunteering programmes in Manchester, Leeds, Liverpool and Sheffield.</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The reason I find this better is you aren't messing with an entire container and thus affecting everything inside. You instead are fixing the issue you're having with a single element.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and it turned out that the cause were (very) slightly different heights at the different columns. This appears to be your case too, because nw_manchester_volunteering.jpg is exactly 1 pixel shorter than the other images.

Hope this helps :-D

Answer (score 0):

In class `.container-fluid` if you delete the `padding-left:15px;` or `padding-right:15px;` attribute then the images align as you are expecting.

Alternatively, you can delete either `padding-left:15px;` , either `padding-right:15px;` from the class `container` which is nested in `.container-fluid` or create a new class for this section of the website where you will have `padding-left:0px;` or `padding-right:0px;` like the below:

```
<div class="container-fluid purple-back">
    <div class="container" style="padding-right:0px;">
        <div class="row margin-100-top margin-100-bot">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 margin-10-eql">
                <img src="/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/images/nw_csr_volunteering.jpg" alt="corporate volunteers in Liverpool">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 margin-10-eql">
                <img src="/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/images/nw_manchester_volunteering.jpg" alt="corporate volunteers in Manchester">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 margin-10-eql">
                <img src="/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/images/nw_manchester_volunteers.jpg" alt="corporate volunteers in Sheffield">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 margin-10-eql">
                <img src="/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/images/nw_leeds_volunteering.jpg" alt="Corporate Volunteers in Leeds">
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">
                    <h1 class="white margin-30-top text-center big">Benefacto helps people organise and run meaningful
                        employee volunteering programmes in Manchester, Leeds, Liverpool and Sheffield.</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

One more solution is to follow the answer of the `Pol Del Aguila` and use the same dimensions for all your pictures.